# Vhost setup in docker in windows 10

Tags: laravel, docker

I am wondering to setup a local domain like edu.test using docker in windows 10.
Previously i used xampp, and there i use two files one: `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`
and another is: `D:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf`
But in docker image i want to do something like that.
I provided my `yml, dockerfile and vhost.conf`

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: .docker/Dockerfile
    image: 'laravelapp'
    ports:
      - 8080:80
      - 8090:80
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: 'laraapp_db'
      MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 1
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ""
    volumes:
      - ./db:/var/lib/mysql

  npm:
    image: node:14
    working_dir: /var/www/html
    entrypoint: ["npm"]
    volumes:
      - "./www/:/var/www/html"
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM php:7.4.1-apache

USER root

WORKDIR /var/www/html

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
        libpng-dev \
        zlib1g-dev \
        libxml2-dev \
        libzip-dev \
        libonig-dev \
        zip \
        curl \
        unzip \
    && docker-php-ext-configure gd \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd \
    && docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql \
    && docker-php-ext-install mysqli \
    && docker-php-ext-install zip \
    && docker-php-source delete \
    && apt-get install -y vim

COPY .docker/vhost.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

RUN curl -XGET -H "Host: edu.test" http://localhost:8080

RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html \
    && a2enmod rewrite
```

**vhost.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/public

    <Directory "/var/www/html">
        AllowOverride all
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:80>
    Servername edu.test
    SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/public"
    <Directory "/var/www/html/public">
             DirectoryIndex index.php
             AllowOverride All
             Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I can only get access http://localhost:8080
But i want to set multiple local test domain .
How can i do that in docker?
Thanks in advance

Comment: What **exactly** is not working when setting the domain in your `hosts` file? How is this related to Laravel itself?

Comment: I can't access to edu.test. I set `127.0.0.1 edu.test` in hosts file. I am trying to run a laravel 6 app.